# How to enable logging for smbd on macOS?

Tags: mojave, logs, plist, file-sharing

I would like to enable logging on my file sharing service. (It's crashing intermittently and I can't figure out why.)

When I inspect the plist for the file sharing service **smbd** on my Mac running Mojave, I see:

```
user@mac:~ $  plutil -p /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist

{
  "AclsEnabled" => 1
  "DOSCodePage" => "437"
  "LocalKerberosRealm" => "LKDC:SHA1..."
  "LogLevel" => 0
  "NetBIOSName" => "transom"
  "ServerDescription" => "Transom"
  "SigningRequired" => 0
}
```

So, it looks like logging is configured with the parameter "LogLevel". 
I've read the smbd man page, and it's not much help, with this parameter.

- What are the allowed log levels?
- Which level is best for debugging **smbd** crashes?
- What's the preferred method for tweaking a value? (plutil can set, or...)

Comment: I have upgraded this machine to macOS Catalina 10.15.2, and things have got much much worse. The Apple smbd currently needs restarting ever couple of hours.

Comment: `smbdiagnose` may be helpful. Don't know when it arrived, but it's in Big Sur.

Answer (score 5):

With macOS 10.15, the only diagnostic logging available for `smbd` is done by grabbing packets.

Apple Support told me the following:

> To enable elevated logging;
>
> ```
> sudo log config --mode level:debug 
> sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist LogLevel -int 1
> sudo /usr/libexec/smb-sync-preferences
> ```
>
> To begin packet capture;
>
> ```
> sudo tcpdump -Pi BSDname -s 0 -K -w /Library/Logs/smb.pcap
> ```
>
> To end packet capture; Control-C
>
> Disable elevated Logging:
>
> ```
> sudo log config --mode level:default 
> sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist LogLevel -int 0 
> sudo /usr/libexec/smb-sync-preferences
> ```

Comment: Is the tcpdump command cut and pasteable, or is BSDname something that needs to be replaced with something else?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about questions 1 and 2, but the third question appears to be scutil.

man scutil tells you about how to do it. Apple uses it to edit that file in the following KB article-
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204021

Comment: Just tried this.  It worked for me - changed the value for key  "LogLevel" in the plist.

Answer (score 1):

I updated to 10.14.5 a few days ago on one of my clients servers and have been having the same problem since. Everyones connection to the server just randomly drops. I can go into activity monitor and quit the smbd process and it will kick right back in and start working again but I never know for how long.